# stuck debugging and fix was very simple

Tags: debugging

I don't know if this happens to you guys but sometimes I get so absorbed debugging an issue that the fix is right in front of your eyes and I can't see it. Getting a friend to look into your code sometimes helps.

Its embarrassing at times, is it just me or this happens to others too? Any tips to avoid this.

Comment: Possibly better on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) as it seems like a "war stories" question to me.

Answer (score 1):

[Talk to the bear](http://www.lenholgate.com/archives/000880.html).

Answer (score 0):

Over the years I've found this happens with less frequency because every time I've gotten rattled to the core over something that turned out to be simple, my brain made a strong mental note to watch out for the same thing in the future.

So I guess I'm saying maybe look at it as a good thing when you get really frustrated but then solve the issue, you might be building up your knowledge base in a lasting way that will save you time down the road.

Comment: Maybe there is no magic pill, now I will always remember to double check byte ordering code in different embedded architectures..... :)